# translation of sentence with multiple って/と in it

Tags: translation

ストレスが原因だっていわれたって聞いたけど

Hi,
what is the meaning of above sentence, the multiple って confuses me, I don't get the meaning of this sentence.
Can some tell me a English translation for this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ストレスが原因だっていわれたって聞いたけど

You can break it up a little bit and replace the って with と for clarity:

ストレスが原因だと言われた - (Someone) was told that stress was the cause.

～と聞いたけど - I heard that ~

So someone heard that someone was told that stress was the cause. けど.