# what is the exact meaning and function of いっちゃいましたよ and しろって in bellow sentence

Tags: particle-に

I know that the meaning of "僕はねはっきり いっちゃいましたよおい黒田をヒーローにしろって。" is “I was clear about it. “hey, make Kuroda the hero!” but I want to know the exact meaning and function of いっちゃいましたよ and しろって

Comment: do you have a picture of the original text? If this is from a manga it sounds like it should be from multiple text bubbles

Comment: this text is related to a part of the dialogue between the High school manager and teachers about a competition between students at " Samurai High School" a Japanese television series. The  High school manager is insisting  that the teachers have to help to only Kuroda:

Comment: part of the main conversation :school manager: 騎馬戦は 当校体育祭のメインイベントです。特に今回は 黒田君のテレビ取材も入っておりますから特に特に 盛り上げなくてはなりません。つまりですね 主役の黒田君に 勝たせたい。というか 勝たせなくてはならないわけなんです。え~ 万がーにも他のチームが勝つことのないようにくれぐれも お願いをいたします。(平野) ご心配なく騎馬戦に出る生徒にはそれとなく言い含めてありますから。僕はね  はっきり いっちゃいましたよおい黒田をヒーローにしろって。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just listing the vocabulary/grammar points,

- 僕はね *I*

[ね](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AD) is a particle expressing emphasis or talking-to-ness.

- はっきり *clearly*
- いっちゃいましたよ *said*

ちゃいました=ちゃう+ました=てしまう+ました=てしまいました. Cf. [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38421/45489). [よ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%88) is an ending particle similar to ね for emphasis.

- おい黒田をヒーローにしろって。 (that) "hey, make Kuroda a hero".

って is a colloquial version of quotative と. Cf. [these](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11016/45489) [questons](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3913/45489).

---

The quote is postponed in the sentence (and as such in the same order as in English). In a very correct version, it would be (dropping ending particles)

- 僕ははっきりと「おい、黒田をヒーローにしろ」といってしまいました。

Comment: Thank you very much